# Multiple diagrams for entity data model

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, edmx

I've read in What's New in Entity Framework 5 Beta:

> You can now create multiple diagrams for each entity data model.
>   Can any one guide me further about this feature and any getting started tutorial about this feature. Is this mean now we can have multiple edmx files to better manage large number of entities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that single EDMX file can now contain multiple diagrams which shows different part of your model mapped in that single EDMX file. Diagram is just a "view" on mapping defined in the EDMX file - previously you could have only single view per EDMX, now you can have more than one.

I don't have VS11 installed on my current machine but as I remember you should be able to select entities in your current diagram and move them to a new / another diagram. You should also be able to manage diagrams and switch between diagrams from model browser.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple diagram in VS 2010. I managed to see it in vs 11

Comment: No it is feature of new designer available only in VS11 - it was available as CTP for VS2010 but it wasn't for production usage.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2012 (previously known as VS 11), yes, you can create multiple diagrams.
Here is how I did it:

1. Create a model in the normal way so that you have a few entities on "[Diagram1]" (see the label on the tab at top).
2. Now CTRL+Click on a few related entities so that you have a couple selected, or just 1 if you prefer.
3. Right Click on one of the selected entities and select "Move to New Diagram"

There may be other ways of doing this, but I haven't found any documentation yet, and also keep in mind that I am using "beta (2)" for EF5 and RC for VS2012, it is likely to change.

Hope that helps,
FJF

Comment: I prefer copy/pasting them into the new diagram.  It seems that by default when you choose "Move to New Diagram", it also removes them (visually) from the source diagram.